# Marathi typing option in wordpress Editor

Tags: php, wordpress

**wordpress**
i want to input marathi language from wordpress editor. After googling a lot, i am got getting how this can be done .There must be some way to do this
Is the a possible to add marathi language in wordpress default  editor .

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress using **wysiwyg** editor, so what ever you input inside that editor it reflect on front end as it is. Please visit below screenshot for getting more reference.

[image]

Here i simply copy-paste Hello word in marathi (Copy from [google translator](https://translate.google.com/#gu/mr/Hello))

Comment: Thanks for resopse @purvik7373 , but i need that functionality in wordpress editor . Without need to coping from google translator